# java regex what the heck? am I misreading the regex docs completey?

Tags: java, regex

```
System.out.println("a".matches("^[A-Za-z]+"));
System.out.println("a ".matches("^[A-Za-z]+"));
```

This gives me:

```
true
false
```

What the heck is up? As far as I am reading it, "[A-Za-z]" includes "a", and "+" means one or more, so this seems like it would work, at least in this universe....

Details are:

Mac OS X 10.8.4

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
```

Maybe I have been writing perl too long and java's regex system is kind of like it but not? No idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String#matches()` tests `this` string against the *entire* pattern. Let's take a trip down JavaDoc lane:

> ### [String#matches(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)
>
> Tells whether or not this string matches the given [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).
>
> An invocation of this method of the form *str*`.matches`(*regex*) yields exactly the same result as the expression
>
> [`Pattern.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)(*regex*, *str*)

so let's trace it through:

> ### [Pattern#matches(String regex, CharSequence input)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
>
> Compiles the given regular expression and attempts to match the given input against it.
>
> An invocation of this convenience method of the form
>
> ```
> Pattern.matches(regex, input);
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the expression
>
> ```
> Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()
> ```

One last step:

> ### [Matcher#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)
>
> **Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.**

There you go. Not evident from the `String#matches(String)` JavaDoc, certainly. The solution is, of course, to use [a method which does not insist on matching the pattern to the entire string.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

Comment: Well, I do not feel so bad. You would think that the String class gets, you know, a little use and the javadoc could help a bit here. O well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("a".matches("^[A-Za-z]+"));   //No space after "a" hence returning true
System.out.println("a ".matches("^[A-Za-z]+"));   //One space after "a" hence returning false
```

If you want to include the space charater change the second to :-

```
System.out.println("a ".matches("^[A-Za-z ]+"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `regex` expression does not contain a space, hance the reason the second returns `false`.